# Exact matching latest selenium chrome driver does not exist, what to do?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Our corporate google chrome has been recently updated to version `91.0.4472.77`, for which I am not able to find chrome driver, which in turn causing problems in our existing automation code.
Can anyone please suggest any way to deal with this?

Answer (score 0):

`Chromdriver` is not available for `91.0.4472.77`

till the time it is available (probably within 2 days) you can try out the beta version

```
ChromeDriver 91.0.4472.19
```

[Download from here](https://sites.google.com/chromium.org/driver/)